# FIXED Menus not showing in Android Studio 0.4.0

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-13.10

I've just updated to Android Studio 0.4.0 and menus are not showing. I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and I have latest JDK installed. ![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tWPP.jpg <-- Image

You can see in the image that Files is the only menu which is showing and when I click it nothing appears

EDIT FIXED: You have to execute the sh in this way: env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home//bin/studio.sh

Comment: With me this problem occurred before the 0.4.0 update. Your workaround doesn't solve the real problem, but it is a good tip. Thank you. I will use it since now. =)